# 2 _ga cookies are generated at the same time

Tags: google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I think Google Analytics sees more visitors than it actually is because 2 _ga cookies are generated at the same time and the user ID are duplicated because of this on my opinion. GA is installed via GTM. Does anyone know why 2 _ga cookies are created and how to fix this error?

Comment: Hmm, I get two as well.  One with and one without the tag/id

Comment: I see two _ga files without the tag ID and I'm afraid it's an issue that is multiplying artificially the number of visitors in our Google Analytics reports.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to guess or look at the cookies really, not at this point of debugging.

Look into the network requests, see if the client id changes from page to page. It shouldn't. All hits within the same session need to have the same client id.

Unless you're purposely maintaining the difference, which you can do, but then you would unlikely ask this question.

If the client id in the hits are indeed changing, then more investigation is required, but it's pretty hard to make it change. You would have to either explicitly do it in GTM/JS, you would have to have various top-level-domains involved, or you would have bad urls that signal to the GA lib to change the client id. Or a few more unlikely options.

//UPD

After taking look at the site, everything becomes pretty obvious: Two GA client ids due to the fact that there is double tracking: UA + GA4. UA uses _ga cookie, GA4 uses the *ga*:
[image]

The cookie is certainly not the same. And here are our two pageviews, one to GA4 and one to UA.

[image]

Again, you don't use cookies to determine what Google does see and what it doesn't. Google's usage of cookies is not obvious, it's subtle. You just go and look at the network requests. They're not subtle, they're very plain.

Comment: The client ID doesn't change. There are 2 different client ID during a session https://tile.expert/fr

Comment: One analytics call can't use two client ids. Your claim makes little sense without more details. I took a look at the site. An explanation is in the answer.